# PyPlot figure not shown in VS Code Jupyter "UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure."

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, julia

I run Julia inside Jupyter notebook within the Microsoft Visual Studio Code IDE.
When I try to make a PyPlot plot, the figure is not shown at and instead I am seeing the following message:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The figure will be shown when a `PyPlot.display_figs()` line will be added at the end of the  cell code (note that the `display_figs` method is not exported so it needs be prepended with `PyPlot`).

[image]

Note that I observe this happening from time to time on some VS Code installation so I publish here this workaround so other people can easily google it.